# FB Like button issue in IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, facebook-like

I have a strange issue with FB Like button integration in IE 7. A picture is worth a thousand words: http://i56.tinypic.com/140ajv9.png.

As you can see, FB buttons overlap dropdown menu when it is opened, so I suppose that it is has something with z-index CSS property.

Did anyone encounter something similar, and of course, can anyone give me some advice for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its a z index issue. Facebook button puts a z index of 1000 on the button. So to fix it add a z index of your own to your own div and give it a z-index greater than 1000. That will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing z-index on the elements? What was the result? Also, try adding position:relative; as well if you are not getting the results you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had same problems with my menu, on hover it was showing the menu 
and overlaped my FB like button.
My solution was this:

<pre>
<!--[if IE 7]> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {            
            $('ul.menu-list li.dir').hover(function() {  
                $('div.fb-like').css("z-index", -1);
            },
            function()
            {            
                $('div.fb-like').css("z-index", 0);
            });
         });    
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
</pre>

Add this on the page where the FB like button is.
```